# Is there a client side mechanism like the `NodeFactory` to create nodes on the server recursively?

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

the server can use the `NodeFactory` to recursively create nodes based on an `ObjectTypeNode`. Is there a similar mechanism for the client?

To be more precise: Can i use the servers's `objectTypeManager.registerObjectType()` to register "types" and trigger the creation of "instances" from the client side?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not like you're thinking.

If the server supports the NodeManagement services in general, and the AddNodes service in particular, all that a Client would need to do is call the AddNodes service and tell the Server to create a Node of some particular Type Defintion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Is the `NodeManagement` service supported by milo and if so, do you have some tips/examples/code spinets to get started?

Comment: It's not implemented for you, but it's possible to implement. If you're using Milo to build a server, your `AddressSpace` implementation would need to override and implement the methods from `NodeManagementServices`. There are not any examples of how to do this, you'll have to look at Part 4 of the OPC UA spec to see how the services should behave.